# Print record when date in one field is within a month from another field (dates in MM-DD-YYYY)

Tags: awk, date, text-formatting

In a nutshell, my main problem is printing a record when date in **one field is within a month from another field**. All dates are in **MM-DD-YYYY** format.

Specifically, I am looking to extract records from a file that contains 108 pipe (`|`) delimited fields, if they meet the following criteria:

1. Date field 14 & 61 must have October data #Resolved
2. Date field 14 must be smaller than date field 15 + 1month ($15 < $14+ 1month) #Not resolved

My code:

```
awk -F'|' '{ if ($14 ~ /10-..-2016/ && $61 ~ /10-..-2016/ && $15< date -d '$14 1 month'  ) print $0}' <input >output
```

The part that's not working is `$15< date -d '$14 1 month'`. The main problem is the MM-DD-YYYY format and that I'm comparing two fields.

Input(I do not have headers, using them just to help explain my sample data. In **bold** the reason for not including the record):
.....|field14|field15|.....|Field61|.....
1.....|10-21-2016|11-**23**-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
2.....|10-21-2016|11-20-2016|.....|**11**-25-2016|.....
3.....|10-21-2016|11-19-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
4.....|10-15-2016|11-10-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
5.....|10-21-2016|**10-19**-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
6.....|**09**-21-2016|09-19-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
Desirable Output(headers used just for explanation):
.....|field14|field15|.....|Field61|.....
3.....|10-21-2016|11-19-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....
4.....|10-21-2016|11-15-2016|.....|10-25-2016|.....

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `date`'s format strings to convert to seconds since epoch (`date +%s`), and then you just have an integer comparison to do.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input file and the output you would want from it. Say one line that should be printed and one that shouldn't. It's very hard to test this sort of thing without any test data.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Can you elaborate? I'm getting an error as `date` is not recognizing MM-DD-YYYY format. Error code: date: invalid date

Comment: You might need to reformat it into `YYYY-MM-DD` from `MM-DD-YYYY`; `date -d` is pretty adaptable but seems to stumble on MDY:  `date -d"2018-04-14" +%s` works for example.

Comment: @terdon provided sample input and output data

Comment: No, I mean actual data. There is no field 13 there. We need something we can test on and see if we produce exactly the output you need. Also, please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -F'[|]' -lane '
   ($m2, $d2, $y2, $m1, $d1, $y1) = map { split /-/ } @F[14,13];

   ($m2, $d2, $y2, $m1, $d1, $y1) =
   ($m1, $d1, $y1, $m2, $d2, $y2) if !($y2 > $y1 or $m2 > $m1 or $d2 > $d1);

   print if
      2 == grep /^10-\d{2}-\d{4}$/, @F[13,60]
                and
      (((12*($y2-$y1)+$m2-$m1) == 1 && ($d2 < $d1))
                    ||
          ((12*($y2-$y1)+$m2-$m1) == 0))
' yourfile
```

## Explanation

We setup an implicit line reading loop and split each line read in using the pipe '|' delimiter and the arrray `@F` which index started at `0` is built up.

Then we stuff month/year/day info from fields `14` and `15` into scalar variables for ease of manipulations later on down under in the code.

And while we're at it, we do a slight tweak to ensure that `m2y2d2` date is always newer than the `m1y1d1` just so as to simplify our date logic calculations down under.

Finally, we decide on printing the current record, aka, line, judging by these 4 criteria, viz.,

- The 14-th element,i.e., `$F[13]` is an `October` month date. AND
- The 61-st element,i.e., `$F[60]` is an `October` month date too. AND
- The two dates are separated by a month, the year has been factored
  in using the term `(y2-y1)*12`, they lie within a month of each other when
  higher date's day is < lower date's day. OR
- The two dates are of the same year, same month => they are within a month
  anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Running `date` for every line would be quite inefficient, you'd be better off using a text-processing tool that can do date calculation by itself like `perl`:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -F'[|]' -lane 'print if
   $F[13] =~ /10-..-2016/ && 
   $F[60] =~ /10-..-2016/ &&
   Time::Piece->strptime($F[14], "%m-%d-%Y") <
     Time::Piece->strptime($F[13], "%m-%d-%Y")->add_months(1)' file
```

Comment: @ Stephane I'm getting error code: `Can't locate Time/Piece.pm`. Given that I found the directory that has `Piece.pm` using `locate piece`, I'm guessing it's installed at the wrong location? Given the above, how can I fix this and is there a way of completing this using only awk?

Comment: @Stephane: `-F'|'` => `-F'\|'` or unambiguous `-F'[|]'`

Comment: @Rakesh, thanks. I had incorrectly assumed it was the same as with `awk` (that when the separator is a single character, it is not treated as a regexp) and did the wrong test to verify (`echo 'a|b'|perl -F '|' -lane 'print $F[0]'`). Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not all that difficult if you use `GNU awk`, which has built-in time functions:

```
$2 ~ /^10/ && $5 ~ /^10/ {
    split($2, t, "-");
    t1 = mktime(t[3] " " t[1] " " t[2] " 0 0 0");
    split($3, t, "-");
    t2 = mktime(t[3] " " t[1] " " t[2] " 0 0 0");
    if (t2 >= t1 && t2 - t1 <= 30*24*3600) {
        print;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michael_Vehrs: The OP wanted to see dates that are within a month of each other, whereas your date logic just looks at whether the before date is older compared to after date.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Thanks for pointing that out. I did not understand what the OP was after.